# Translate the coordinates of a sprite into coordinates on screen

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

In LibGDX, how would one translate to coordinates of a sprite into the coordinates on-screen?

For example,  in a 100x100 sprite, how can I find out where 25, 50 on a specific sprite is on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Actor/Stage setup. Create an Actor to carry your sprite, then call `myActor.localToScreenCoordinates(Vector2 localCoords)`.

You can learn more about the Actor class from the [official LibGDX documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html). There are many handy coordinate translation methods within the Actor class.